# How to increase retention of download history in Firefox?

Tags: firefox, download, history

Whenever I want to find a file that I remember downloading in Firefox download history, I fail unless it was very recent. It seems to remember about 30 items or so.

I don't think this history takes much disk space. Can I increase it to significantly higher number? I tried to search in `about:config`, but did not find anything that seemed relevant.

Comment: From a deleted answer:   you can try the following: Go to Firefox > Options > Privacy Select Use custom settings for history

Answer (score 0):

If you click on the download icon, only a few items are shown.

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>J</kbd> to view the entire download history, *from the last time it was cleared*.  As far as I know, the only limit on retention is if one chooses to clear history on closing, or clear it manually.

[image: Downloads]

Comment: I don't think this is true at all. For example on my work laptop, I never cleared history. I see last download at 2023-11-11, yet I definitelly download many files each month. On my personal PC, the file history ends with 2023-11-08, so both histories on unrelated machines end in the same week. Even though I never cleared either.

Comment: Note that in my question, I mention seeing around 30 items, which is much more than the 4 or so you see when you click the download icon, so I was refering to the `Ctrl+J` window.

Answer (score 0):

When in private mode, only up to 42 items are retrieved from history and displayed.

If this is the case, there is no way to change the value. It is hardcoded.